# Finding Fourier Coefficient Of PDE

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=sin(m\pi x)sin(\omega t),\quad0<x<1 ,t>0\\
u(x,0)=sin(x),\quad 0\leq x\leq 1\\
u_t(x,0)=1+x, \quad 0\leq x\leq 1\\
u(0,t)=u(1,0)=0,\quad t\geq0
\end{cases}
$$

Where $m\in \mathbb{N}, \omega \in \mathbb{R}, \omega\neq m \pi$

For the homognous part I got:

$$u^h(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}sin(n\pi x)[A_ncos(n\pi t)+B_nsin(n\pi t)]$$

Using the first initial condition we get

$$sin x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n sin(n\pi x)$$

$$sin x=A_1 sin(\pi x)$$

So it is $A_1=1$ for $x\notin\mathbb{N}$?

I tried using Fourier coefficents and got the following integral

$$A_n=2\int_{0}^{1}sin(x)sin(n\pi x)dx$$

How can it be integrated?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

$$ A_n=2\int_{0}^{1}sin(x)sin(n\pi x)dx = \int_{0}^{1} \left(cos((1 - n\pi)x) - cos((1 + n\pi)x)\right) dx, $$ and take it from there.

Comment: The answer is not a constant

Comment: Well, I was just answering the 'how can this be integrated?' question since your reasoning seems ok to me. So, that being the case, can I ask: Does $A_n$ have to be a constant?

Comment: Correct, I know that if we have cos/sin we can use it with an equation to the Fourier series to find the coefficient, but because it did not work out, I tried the integral